# Как объяснить постановку выделенной запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

"И теперь она была как в истерике,  суетилась,  смеялась судорожно,  припадочно (,) особенно на возражения встревоженного Тоцкого".

Как объяснить постановку выделенной запятой? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

В данном предложении запятой выделяется так называемая присоединительная конструкция, которая начинается обычно со слов "особенно, в особенности, даже, в частности, главным образом, например, в том числе, и притом, да и, да и вообще  и др".